# Simplifying/condensing long time series functions in R

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series

I have a long time series loop that I would like to simplify/condense. I am trying to simulate the calving of a cattle herd over a period of ten years (monthly intervals) using a random binomial distribution. The function starts with the assumption that the cattle have been covered by the bull. Each variable is affected by the previous. The variables are as follows:

G1:G9 gestation for each month.
MC1:MC7 mothers with calves for 7 months, then after the calves are weaned.
Rest1:Rest6 periods of rest before they are covered by the bull again.
DeadCows based on the mortality rate.
NPreg non-pregnant cows based on the conception rate.

Inputs:
size_cowherd, number of cattle in the herd.
concep, conception rate.

Thanks in advance.

The code I have is as follows:

```
size_cowherd<-100
concep<-0.95

cows <- function(t=119, mort=0.0005){
  G1<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G2<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G3<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G4<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G5<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G6<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G7<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G8<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  G9<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC1<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC2<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC3<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC4<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC5<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC6<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  MC7<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  Rest1<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  Rest2<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  Rest3<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  Rest4<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  Rest5<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  Rest6<- numeric(length = t + 1)
  DeadCows <- numeric(length = t + 1)
  NPreg <- numeric(length = t + 1)

  G1[1]<- rbinom(1,size_cowherd,concep)
  G2[1]<- 0
  G3[1]<- 0
  G4[1]<- 0
  G5[1]<- 0
  G6[1]<- 0
  G7[1]<- 0
  G8[1]<- 0
  G9[1]<- 0
  MC1[1]<- 0
  MC2[1]<- 0
  MC3[1]<- 0
  MC4[1]<- 0
  MC5[1]<- 0
  MC6[1]<- 0
  MC7[1]<- 0
  Rest1[1]<-0
  Rest2[1]<-0
  Rest3[1]<-0
  Rest4[1]<-0
  Rest5[1]<-0
  Rest6[1]<-0
  DeadCows[1] <- 0
  NPreg[1] <- size_cowherd - G1[1] 

  for(step in 1:t){
    G2[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G1[step], (1-mort))
    G3[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G2[step], (1-mort))
    G4[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G3[step], (1-mort))
    G5[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G4[step], (1-mort))
    G6[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G5[step], (1-mort))
    G7[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G6[step], (1-mort))
    G8[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G7[step], (1-mort))
    G9[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G8[step], (1-mort))
    MC1[step+1] <- rbinom(1, G9[step], (1-mort))
    MC2[step+1] <- rbinom(1, MC1[step], (1-mort))
    MC3[step+1] <- rbinom(1, MC2[step], (1-mort))
   MC4[step+1] <- rbinom(1, MC3[step], (1-mort))
   MC5[step+1] <- rbinom(1, MC4[step], (1-mort))
   MC6[step+1] <- rbinom(1, MC5[step], (1-mort))
   MC7[step+1] <- rbinom(1, MC6[step], (1-mort))
   Rest1[step+1] <- rbinom(1,MC7[step],(1-mort))
   Rest2[step+1] <- rbinom(1,Rest1[step],(1-mort))
   Rest3[step+1] <- rbinom(1,Rest2[step],(1-mort))
   Rest4[step+1] <- rbinom(1,Rest3[step],(1-mort))
   Rest5[step+1] <- rbinom(1,Rest4[step],(1-mort))
   Rest6[step+1] <- rbinom(1,Rest5[step],(1-mort))
   G1[step+1] <- rbinom(1, Rest6[step], (1-mort))
   DeadCows[step+1] <-sum(G1[step]-G2[step+1],G2[step]-G3[step+1],G3[step]-
    G4[step+1],G4[step]-G5[step+1],G5[step]-G6[step+1],G6[step]-
    G7[step+1],G7[step]-G8[step+1],G8[step]-G9[step+1],G9[step]-
    MC1[step+1],MC1[step]-MC2[step+1],MC2[step]-MC3[step+1],MC3[step]-
    MC4[step+1],MC4[step]-MC5[step+1],MC5[step]-MC6[step+1],MC6[step]-
    MC7[step+1],MC7[step]-Rest1[step+1],Rest1[step]-
    Rest2[step+1],Rest2[step]-Rest3[step+1],Rest3[step]-
    Rest4[step+1],Rest4[step]-Rest5[step+1],Rest5[step]-
    Rest6[step+1],Rest6[step]-G1[step+1])

      if(G1[step]<size_cowherd){
        G1[step+1]<- rbinom(1,Rest6[step], concep)
        NPreg[step+1]<-Rest6[step]-G1[step+1]
      }
  }
  out <-cbind(G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8,G9,MC1,MC2,MC3,MC4,MC5,MC6,MC7,Rest1,R
  est2,Rest3,Rest4,Rest5,Rest6,DeadCows,NPreg)
  return(out)
 }
```

Below is a sample of what the output should look like. In the 23rd month, the cycle restarts again.

```
    G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8 G9 MC1 MC2 MC3 MC4 MC5 MC6 MC7 Rest1 Rest2 Rest3 
     Rest4 Rest5 Rest6 DeadCows NPreg
1   96  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     4
2    0 96  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
3    0  0 96  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
4    0  0  0 96  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
5    0  0  0  0 96  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
6    0  0  0  0  0 96  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
7    0  0  0  0  0  0 96  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
8    0  0  0  0  0  0  0 96  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
9    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 96   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
10   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  96   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
11   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  96   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
12   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0  96   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
13   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0  96   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
14   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0  96   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
15   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  96   0     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
16   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  96     0     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
17   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    96     0     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
18   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0    96     0     
       0     0     0        0     0
19   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0    95     
       0     0     0        1     0
20   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0    
      95     0     0        0     0
21   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0    95     0        0     0
22   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     
       0     0    94        1     0
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of what the intended output looks like, please?

Comment: @shea Yes, here it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you. I think the trick here is to make use of matrices to keep the bookkeeping a bit more straightforward.

```
 size_cowherd <- 100

 concep <- 0.95

 stage_names <- c(paste0("G",seq(9)), paste0("MC",seq(7)), paste0("Rest",seq(6)))

 cows <- function(size_cowherd, concep, t=220, mort=0.0005, names=stage_names) {
   n_stages <- length(names)
   stages <- matrix(0, t, n_stages)
   dead_cows <- n_preg <- rep(NA, t)
   stages[1,1] <- rbinom(1, size_cowherd, concep)
   dead_cows[1] <- 0
   n_preg[1] <- size_cowherd - stages[1,1]
   for(tt in 2:t) {
     stages[tt,1] <- rbinom(1, stages[tt-1,n_stages], 1-mort)
     for(i in 2:n_stages) {
       stages[tt,i] <- rbinom(1, stages[tt-1,i-1], 1-mort)
     }
     dead_cows[tt] <- sum(stages[tt-1,] - stages[tt,c(2:n_stages,1)])
     if(stages[tt-1,1] < size_cowherd) {
       stages[tt, 1] <- rbinom(1, stages[tt-1,n_stages], concep)
       n_preg[tt] <- stages[tt-1,n_stages] - stages[tt,1]
     }
   }
   res <- cbind(stages, dead_cows, n_preg)
   colnames(res) <- c(names, "Dead", "N_Preg")
   return(res)
 }

 head(cows(100, 0.95), 24)

       G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8 G9 MC1 MC2 MC3 MC4 MC5 MC6 MC7 Rest1 Rest2 Rest3 Rest4 Rest5 Rest6 Dead N_Preg
  [1,] 96  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      4
  [2,]  0 96  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
  [3,]  0  0 96  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
  [4,]  0  0  0 96  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
  [5,]  0  0  0  0 96  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
  [6,]  0  0  0  0  0 96  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
  [7,]  0  0  0  0  0  0 95  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    1      0
  [8,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 95  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
  [9,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 95   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
 [10,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  95   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
 [11,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  95   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
 [12,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0  95   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
 [13,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0  95   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
 [14,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0  95   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
 [15,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  95   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
 [16,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  95     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
 [17,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    94     0     0     0     0     0    1      0
 [18,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0    94     0     0     0     0    0      0
 [19,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0    94     0     0     0    0      0
 [20,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0    94     0     0    0      0
 [21,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0    94     0    0      0
 [22,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0    94    0      0
 [23,] 92  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      2
 [24,]  0 92  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0
```

Comment: How would one use this approach to generate a more simple and readable output so that a Column name would represent the sum of the stage sequence, e.g. PregCows would show the simulation for nine rows under the same column name and so on?

Comment: @Francis_SU Can you clarify your request? For example, do you want a table with 10 rows & 22 cols, where each row is a "run", or do you want a table with 1 row & 22 cols where each col is the sum of all of the cols?

Comment: Yes, excuse the lack of clarity. I'm looking for a table with `t` rows and 5 columns, where `G1` - `G9` becomes `G` `MC1` - `MC7` becomes `MC` and continued to achieve `Rest`. Where `G2` `[2,]` is equal to `96` will then be seen under `G` in row `[2,]`. What I am looking for is a matrix less wide than the above. @mark S